# How to get the individual words from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
input = (Columbia and (India  or Singapore) and Malaysia)

output = [Columbia, India, Singapore, Malaysia]
```

Basically ignore the python keywords and brackets

I tried with the below code, but still not able to eliminate the braces.

```
import keyword

my_str=input()
l1=list(my_str.split(" "))
l2=[x for x in l1 if not keyword.iskeyword((x.lower()))]
print(l2)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be tagged with both python 3 **and** python 2?

Comment: @superStormer Oopsy removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
import re
from keyword import iskeyword

inp = '(Columbia and (India or Singapore) and Malaysia)'

c = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')

print([i.group() for i in c.finditer(inp) if not iskeyword(i.group().lower())])
```

output :

```
['Columbia', 'India', 'Singapore', 'Malaysia']
```

without regex :

```
from keyword import iskeyword

inp = '(Columbia and (India or Singapore) and Malaysia)'

res = []
for i in inp.split():
    stripped = i.strip('()[]{}')
    if not iskeyword(stripped):
        res.append(stripped)

print(res)
```

Comment: @sivaperumal10000 I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import keyword
my_str=input()
my_str = re.sub(r'[\(\)\[\]{}]','',my_str)
l1=list(my_str.split(" "))
l2=[x for x in l1 if not keyword.iskeyword((x.lower()))]
print(l2)
```

`re.sub(r'[\(\)\[\]{}]','',my_str)`

This will replace all kinds of braces with empty strings (thus removing them).

Comment: Actually no need for replacement, You can do it in one shot.

Comment: Also this breaks if the input has more than one space which is valid in python and ignored by the interpreter.

Comment: There is an unnecessary `list()`, `split` returns a list itself.

Comment: `list()` was in original code I just added 1 line